# How to test Firebase FCM locally

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to run some FCM examples on my local firebase server

firebase serve --only functions,hosting

but I am getting an authorization error

info: Error sending message: { Error: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. Raw server response:

how to run FCM examples locally ?

Comment: By testing locally, do you actually mean without internet connection as well?

Comment: with internet of course because I am getting an error message.

Comment: What if I want to use it without internet? I mean locally?

Answer (score 12):

You need to make sure you have setup the authentication in the right way. Firestore and realtime triggers have authentication setup default, but for other API's including FCM you need to give access. The steps are described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Copied:

- Open the Service Accounts pane of the Google Cloud Console.
- Make sure that App Engine default service account is selected, and
  use the options menu at right to select Create key.
- When prompted, select JSON for the key type, and click Create.
- Set your Google default credentials to point to the downloaded key: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key.json"` and then try again
  `firebase serve --only functions`

Comment: For me to resolve, I also needed to enable the Cloud Messaging API in the Google Cloud Console.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me try it:

1. Go to google cloud.
2. Go to API and Services.
3. Enable API and Services.
4. Turn on the cloud messaging and Turn on Firebase cloud messaging API.